# Program still in taskmanager after calling Halt

Tags: delphi, indy10

The problem is that as my first executable statements I want to check if I can read from a databse. If I can't, I call `MessageDlg` to explain so, then I `Halt;`.

However, after closing the dialog, I still see the application in the tak manager (and if I stop it and re-run the application, the same thing occurs).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

Global.ADQuery1 is an AnyDac database access component. I access the d/b by IP address. The code works fine when I set my PCs address to the d/b address and gives the reported problem when I change my IP address (hence, can't access the d/b, which throws an exception).

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   try
      Global.ADQuery1.Open('SHOW DATABASES');

   except
      On E: Exception do
      begin
         MessageDlg('Database access problem', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
         Halt;
      end;
   end;
```

[update] when I run in the IDE, after catching

`(EMySQLNativeException) : "[AnyDAC][Phys][MySQL] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.21.18.211' (10060)"`

I catch an `EIdWinSockStubError  either the program has not called wsastartup or wsastartup failed` - but I don't udnertsand how it is thrown ... I guess that `Application.Terminate` calls may main form's `FormClose`, which doesn't do anything with my Indy components, but I guess that when the parent form is destroyed then its children will be too.

---

[further update]

My `TMainForm.FormCreate` now says only

```
Sleep(1000);
PostMessage(Handle, UM_PROGRAM_START, 0, 0);
```

And I moved all the code into the stat of function that handles that. Surely everything is created at that time? So, why does my Indy component throw an exception?

Maybe I should put the `PostMessage()` in my [application].pas after `Application.Run();` ?

(Aside: 1) how do others generally handle application start in this way?   2) does anyone have an application skeleton? I was thinking of creating one with options to handle minimize to system tray, only allow one instance, recent files menu, etc, etc) - although that might be better as a separate question

Comment: Try `Application.Terminate` instead perhaps?

Comment: First, calling `Halt`; it should be a last resort. Second, not posting any source code whatsoever in your question; it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong when you don't show what you're doing.

Comment: +1 to both. Ah, Ken, you always want to see the code ;-) Ok, updated ...  and Application.Terminate didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Use the debugger. Pause your program and look at the call stack to see what your program is still doing and what it's waiting for.

Comment: +1 but I don't see a stack ??? maybe a thread still runing???

Comment: Maybe. Again, use the debugger. It can show you all the threads, and it can show you what each is doing. There is definitely a call stack; certain Delphi versions put it on the View, Debug Windows menu, so maybe that's where it is on yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Halt` procedure is not the immediate process-killer we sometimes mistake it for. It calls the unit-finalization sections of all your program's units, so your program might be stuck in one of those, perhaps waiting for something to happen to your form, which isn't going to happen since your `OnCreate` handler hasn't returned yet.

You could use the debugger to find out what your program is doing or waiting for.

To *really* get out of a program as fast as possible, skip `Halt` and go straight to `ExitProcess`. That's the final thing `Halt` calls.

`Application.Terminate` is actually *farther* from the point where any real termination occurs since it's really just an advisory command; the application won't terminate until it reaches the message loop.

Better yet, find a more graceful way to exit your program. For example, test your database *before* creating your form so you're not left in the awkward position of having a half-created form that you don't really want anymore.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Rob ExitProcess(0) did the trick (of course, there may still be a memory leak, but I have to accept that)

Comment: @Mawg `ExitProcess` can't leak memory. System claims it all back. But you really ought not to need to call `ExitProcess`. It indicates that there's something else not quite right in your app.